# Node breaks JSON string in URL on 'equal' sign =

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am receiving user object from FB API on a React client (localhost:3000).
Then i'm sending it to my node server (localhost:4000)
When the object is received on the node route and i console log it, it SPLITS any value that has '=' sign to ': ' (colon and space). That's breaking my JSON object.

original object being sent from client: (problem is in imageUrl key equal signs)

```
userInfo {
about: "abcde"
age: 26
email: "test@test.com"
fbProfileLink: "www.some-profile-link-here.com"
gender: "male"
id: null
imageUrl: "https://url-url.url.url/platform/profilepic/?asid=3422352323&height=50&width=50&ext=3422352323&hash=hash"
language: {mainLang: "", speaksEnglish: true}
name: "abcde"
residence: "abcde"
}
```

This is how i get it in the node server: (turns to 'asid': ...)

```
"imageUrl":"https://url-url.url.url/url/profilepic/?asid': '3422352323',
  height: '50',
  width: '50',
  ext: '3422352323',
hash: 'hash'
```

router function:

```
router.post("/post-test", (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("hi amit POST")
    console.dir(req.body)
    res.end()
})
```

request sending from client:

```
axios.post("http://localhost:4000/post-test", user, {
                    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
                })
                .then(res => {})
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
```

its like its breaking the string to query params but i just want it as a string

Comment: Show us the route handler code and the client code.

Comment: code snippets added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
axios.post("http://localhost:4000/post-test", user, {
  headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
})
```

Here, you are telling the server that you are sending `form-urlencoded` data. URL-encoded data follows the `key=value&key2=value2` format. The server sees the Content-Type header and tries to parse your JSON as URL-encoded data.

Change the Content-Type to the JSON one:

```
axios.post("http://localhost:4000/post-test", user, {
  headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are sending an incorrect header which is causing the server to parse the values incorrectly.

Change 
`{"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}`

to
`{"Content-Type": "application/json"}`

Comment: and now im getting empty object: { }

Comment: You will need to add the body parser middleware before your routes: `router.use(bodyParser.json())`. See here for examples if it's not clear: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Comment: I didnt use bodyparser because its not needed anymore as express has it built-in, but i missed adding this middleware (which replaces bodyparser): app.use(express.json())
Now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm Assuming you're using express with body parser.
In order to make it work with json, consider bootstrapping your app in the following way:

#### Server

```
const express = require("express")
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

#### Client

```
axios.post("http://localhost:4000/post-test", user, {
  headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
});
```

#### Payload

```
{
  "about": "abcde",
  "age": 26,
  "email": "test@test.com",
  "fbProfileLink": "www.some-profile-link-here.com",
  "gender": "male",
  "id": null,
  "imageUrl": "https://url-url.url.url/platform/profilepic/?asid=3422352323&height=50&width=50&ext=3422352323&hash=hash",
  "language": {
    "mainLang": "",
    "speaksEnglish": true
  },
  "name": "abcde",
  "residence": "abcde"
}
```

Result

```
hi amit POST
{ about: 'abcde',
  age: 26,
  email: 'test@test.com',
  fbProfileLink: 'www.some-profile-link-here.com',
  gender: 'male',
  id: null,
  imageUrl:
   'https://url-url.url.url/platform/profilepic/?asid=3422352323&height=50&width=50&ext=3422352323&hash=hash',
  language: { mainLang: '', speaksEnglish: true },
  name: 'abcde',
  residence: 'abcde' }
```